# pythonでcsv や Excel のファイルを一度に読み込みたい

Tags: python, excel, csv

Pythonでデータファイルを一度に読み込むにはどうすればいいのでしょうか．

例えば，`data1.xls〜data100.xls`というファイルをxlrdで読み込みたいとき．

`book1 = xlrd.open_workbook('data1.xls')`

を100回書くのは手間ですし，多分そういうことは皆さんしないと思います．

初歩的な質問ですが，ご存知の方がおられましたらご教授ください．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ファイルが連番なら、順に読んでリストに格納しておけば良いのではないでしょうか。

```
book_list = []
for n in range(1, 101):
    file_name = 'data%d.xls' % (n)
    book_list.append(xlrd.open_workbook(file_name))
```

フォルダ内のxlsファイルを全部読むなら、ディクショナリに格納するのはどうでしょうか。

```
import os, glob
dir = '/path/to/dir/*.xls'
book_dict = {}
for file_path in glob.glob(dir):
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    book_dict[file_name] = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
```